# Delete multiple columns from Multiple sheets

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, dictionary

I am trying to delete Multiple columns from Multiple sheets while retaining those found in a list.

For example I have `sheet1`, `sheet2`, `sheet3`, ..., `sheet7`.
From these sheets I have particular columns to be keep like.

From `sheet1` I want keep columns like `s.no`, `cust.name`, `product`, `date` remaining all should be deleted same from `sheet2` I want to keep `prod.disc,address`, `pin` remaining all should be deleted like I have remaining sheets in that I want to keep particular columns remaining all should be deleted.
I am trying to do using arrays but not able start how to do. I have basic syntax.

```
Sub sbVBS_To_Delete_Specific_Multiple_Columns()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A,C:C,H:H,K:O,Q:U").EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub`[code]
```

But that didn't work for me because in future some columns may add in it and I want columns should recognize  with name which column to keep and remaining to discard.

Comment: Start by deleting a single column. If the column caption is the name which you specify delete it. In the next step create a loop which repeats the action with another caption. To find the caption, you need to loop through all the captions in your sheet or use the Find function.

Comment: can you provide me basic syntax??

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is the basic code. Specify the worksheet and the columns to be deleted in the main procedure. Set the row in which to find the captions in the sub-procedure.

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
    ' 17 Mar 2017

    Dim ClmCaption As Variant
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    ' better to specify the sheet by name, like Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("My Excel")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False      ' freeze screen (speeds up execution)
    ClmCaption = Array("One", "two", "three", "four", "five")
    ' specify all the columns you want to delete by caption , not case sensitive

    For i = 0 To UBound(ClmCaption)         ' loop through all the captions
        DelColumn Ws, CStr(ClmCaption(i))   ' call the sub for each caption
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True       ' update screen
End Sub

Private Sub DelColumn(Ws As Worksheet, Cap As String)
    ' 17 Mar 2017

    Dim CapRow As Long
    Dim Fnd As Range

    CapRow = 3                              ' this is the row where the captions are
    Set Fnd = Ws.Rows(CapRow).Find(Cap)     ' find the caption
    If Fnd Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The caption """ & Cap & """ doesn't exist." & vbCr & _
               "The column wasn't deleted.", _
               vbInformation, "Invalid parameter"
    Else
        Ws.Columns(Fnd.Column).EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End If
End Sub
```

You can run the code as it is but you will get a lot of error messages because the specified captions don't exist.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt response the first code looks good but as i mentioned before i want to keep 'dict("Sheet1") = Array("s.no", "cust.name", "product", "date")
    dict("Sheet2") = Array("prod.disc", "address", "pin")
    dict("Sheet50") = Array("foo", "bar")' column names should be intact in sheet and remaining  columns  should be deleted

Comment: @Kittu - Where is it mentioned that you are using a dictionary with arrays as the columns to retain and why wasn't your original question above edited to include that salient fact?

Comment: Your comment doesn't appear to refer to the code I posted. Since I took time to write it, at your request, it would be nice if you would at least look at it instead of appending correspondence to it which you seem to have with someone else.

Comment: @Variatus thanks for the code ..it really helped me to recreate the code

Answer (score 0):

The following uses a Scripting Dictionary object that maintains a list of worksheets to be processed as the dictionary **keys** with an array of column header labels to keep as the associated **items**.

```
Option Explicit

Sub delColumnsNotInDictionary()
    Dim d As Long, ky As Variant, dict As Object
    Dim c As Long, lc As Long

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare

    dict.Item("Sheet1") = Array("s.no", "cust.name", "product", "date")
    dict.Item("Sheet2") = Array("prod.disc", "address", "pin")
    dict.Item("Sheet50") = Array("foo", "bar")

    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each ky In dict.keys
            With Worksheets(ky)
                lc = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                 MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
                For c = lc To 1 Step -1
                    'filter array method of 'not found in array'
                    'WARNING! CASE SENSITIVE SEARCH  - foo <> FOO
                    If UBound(Filter(dict.Item(ky), .Cells(1, c).Value2)) = -1 Then
                        '.Cells(1, c).EntireColumn.Delete
                    Else
                        Debug.Print .Cells(1, c).Value2 & " at " & _
                          UBound(Filter(dict.Item(ky), .Cells(1, c).Value2))
                    End If
                    'worksheet MATCH method of 'not found in array'
                    'Case insensitive search - foo == FOO
                    If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(1, c).Value2, dict.Item(ky), 0)) Then
                        .Cells(1, c).EntireColumn.Delete
                    Else
                        Debug.Print .Cells(1, c).Value2 & " at " & _
                          Application.Match(.Cells(1, c).Value2, dict.Item(ky), 0)
                    End If
                Next c
            End With
        Next ky
    End With

    dict.RemoveAll: Set dict = Nothing

End Sub
```

Note that I have included two methods for determining whether a column header label is within the array of columns to keep. One is case-sensitive (the array Filter method) and the other is not (worksheet function MATCH method). The case-insensitive search method is currently active.

Comment: this code is working for me but 'dict.Item("Sheet1") = Array("Requested id", "Module", "Product", "Status")' in sheet1 its deleting "Requested id" also , didn't understand why?

Comment: Look for leading or trailing spaces, double spaces or other non-printing characters in the worksheet header label. `=LEN(<cell with 'Requested id'>)` should return 12.

Comment: its returning 12 and tried with "dict.Item("Sheet1") = Array("Requestor", "Module", "Product", "Status") i tried replacing with Requestor and its deleting "Requestor" also :-(

Comment: Hmmm... I really couldn't say without actually working on the data and that is beyond the scope here. Use a Watch on the .cells(1, c).value2 and try `?.cells(1, c).value2=dict.Item("Sheet1")(0)` in the Immediate window perhaps.

Comment: when i applied this code to my live data i am getting application defined or object defined error at 'lc = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                 MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column'

Comment: The only way I can see that happening is if the referenced worksheet is **completely blank**. I did not foresee that eventuality so you will need to provide error control in that situation.